# VB Dot Net Binding records to a listview base on the first letter

Tags: vb.net

Please i want to select list of products base on the first letter by keypress in a textbox.

This is how i load records to the listview from the database.

Try
            cmd.CommandText = ("Select ProductCode From STOCK_DETAILS")
            cmd.Connection = net_55
            Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet

```
        Da.Fill(Ds, "STOCK_DETAILS")
        Dim Bs As New BindingSource
        Bs.DataSource = Ds
        Bs.DataMember = "STOCK_DETAILS"


        With ProductListView
            For i As Integer = 0 To Bs.Count - 1
                Dim lst As New ListViewItem
                With lst
                    .Text = Bs.Current("ProductCode").ToString
                    '.SubItems.Add(Bs.Current("CompanyName").ToString)
                End With
                .Items.Add(lst)
                Bs.MoveNext()
            Next
        End With
```

The above code here will bind all the records in that column to the listview.
But this is not what i want to achieve.

For example the select statement here in SQL helps me achieve my goal at the back end. This same code is not working at the VB side.

Select ProductCode  From STOCK_DETAILS 
Where ProductCode Like 'H%'

Any help would grateful.

Comment: Please provide a little more info. Is your problem, that you do not know how to connect the text entered in the textbox to your data source or is it that you do not know how to update the datasource to show the results of the updates sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was acceptable to perform the filter at the SQL level, you could try passing the first letter of the TextBox into the SQL string. Something like this:

```
Dim commandText As String = String.Format("SELECT ProductCode FROM STOCK_DETAILS WHERE ProductCode LIKE '{0}%'", textBoxValue)
cmd.CommandText = (commandText)

cmd.Connection = net_55

Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

Dim Ds As New DataSet

Da.Fill(Ds, "STOCK_DETAILS")
Dim Bs As New BindingSource
Bs.DataSource = Ds
Bs.DataMember = "STOCK_DETAILS"
```

The above code could be called from a text changed event in the TextBox.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Call GetData(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please this is what i want. For instance i have hundred products in my database. And i do  not want to select all the hundred products to bind the listview control but rather select them based on the letter the user type in.Eg I have the following prducts. 1. Pen,2.Book,3.Bag,4.Fan,5.Phone,6Belt,7Shirt. So for now looking at the available products in the table i want to select products that start with b only to bind them to the listview control on a keypress in a textbox. I hope this explanation will help. Thank Markus and Nathanael for your concern.

Comment: Please Nathanael, how can I get such result only by a text change event.

Comment: In my example you would place your code where you bind the data to the ListView in a procedure named GetData that accepts a string argument. The GetData procedure would then be called from the TextBox text changed event.